# ifelse with multiple condition for creating new variable in data.table R

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

I have a `data.table` and want to create a new variable based on multiple conditions in an `ifelse` statement but what I get as a result seems to be strange.

Let's imagine the following simplified example.

```r
DT <- data.table(replicate(2,sample(0:1,5,replace=TRUE)))

   V1 V2
1:  1  0
2:  1  1
3:  1  1
4:  1  0
5:  0  1
```

I want to create a new variable based on the existing variables. I use the `ifelse` statement as follows:

```r
DT[, new.var := ifelse(V1 > 0, 1, 0)]
DT[, new.var.mult := ifelse(V1 > 0 && V2 > 0, 1, 0)]
```

However, this does not work in case of multiple conditions. (I am aware that this task could be solved easily without multiple condition but my problem is more complicated.)

```r
   V1 V2 new_var new_var_multiple
1:  1  0       1                0
2:  1  1       1                0
3:  1  1       1                0
4:  1  0       1                0
5:  0  1       0                0
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: You don't need an `ifelse` here, just do `DT[, new_var_multiple := (V1 > 0 & V2 > 0) + 0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use only one ampersand (&) to compare vectors.

```
DT[, new.var.mult := ifelse(V1 > 0 & V2 > 0, 1, 0)]
```

Illustration:

```
> c(TRUE, TRUE) & c(FALSE, TRUE)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
> c(TRUE, TRUE) && c(FALSE, TRUE)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Avoid `ifelse` within data.tables. I don't think it is optimized (yet?). I'd just do something like `DT[, x := "a"]; DT[condition, x := "b"]` if David's comment doesn't apply.

Comment: @Roland is that still the case?

Comment: @posdef I believe it, if I haven't missed something. I doubt that optimizing `ifelse` is a priority for Matt and Arun. Most advanced R programmers seem to avoid `ifelse`anyway.